# set checkmark in uitableView as the data is being loaded in the cell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to checkmark the data when the data is being loaded in the `uitablecell`. I know it works when you put it in the `didselect` section but can we use it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If yes how to use it? I have tried but it doesn't show any checkmarks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AddGoalsTableViewCell";

AddGoalsTableViewCell *cell = (AddGoalsTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddGoalsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.addGoalsText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:17];
cell.addGoalsText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.addGoalsText.text = [[goalsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    PFObject *currentUser = [[goalsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];
    User *user = [[User alloc] initWithUserId:[currentUser valueForKey:@"userID"] userName:[currentUser valueForKey:@"name"] anduserpassword:[currentUser valueForKey:@"password"]];

    if(user==nil)
    {

    }
    else if([[user userId]isEqualToString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] ] lowercaseString]])
    {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;  <------Here
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }


return cell;
}
```

Comment: here you are using custom cell, you cant use accessoryType .... so you need to add image inside your cell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil )
    {
        cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

// UITableView Delegate Method
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And lastIndexPath is a property(retain) NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath;

Comment: I think his answer is correct,then why you guys are giving negative mark?

Comment: @iPhone Why reload data in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, why don't you get the cell for that index path and set the accessoryType ?